# AWS Lambda: exports.handler not running promise functions

Tags: aws-lambda

This is not working:

```
exports.handler = (username, password) => {
    return {
        login: () => login(username, password),
        processLogin,
        generateReport
    };
};
```

When I change to this it works, but...

```
exports.handler = (username, password) => {

    login(username, password);
    processLogin();
    generateReport();
};
```

...it doesn't follow the order. How to make it work on AWS Lambda? In my understanding, the process is follows, first `login` is run, when it is done `processLogin` starts, when it is done `generateReport` starts. `generateReport` looks like this:

```
function generateReport(token)...
```

which means that the functions grabs some argument from `processLogin` which runs before that. Anyways, how do I make it work?

Please let me know if additional info needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version does not return a `Promise`, but instead returns an object. No code is executed. Additionally, the handler parameters should match the AWS API.

Your code should explicitly return a promise:

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  username = extractUsername(event);
  password = extractPassword(event);

  return Promise.resolve()
           .then(() => login(username, password))
           .then(() => processLogin())
           .then(() => generateReport())
           .catch(err) => handleError());
}
```